# Highlight selected menu item in a web page

Tags: html, css

My menu html look like:

```
<i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
<a class="scroll" href="#intro">Home</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .menu a:hover 
 {
   background:#e9d319;
   color: #000;
  }

 .menu a.active
 {
 background:#e9d319;
 color: #000;
 }
```

I need every menu must be highlighted when i'm seeing pages.Suppose i am looking services it must be highlighted.

How to do that?

Comment: For that you'll need to write code… have you searched anything? tried anything..?

Comment: yes i tried <div class="active"> like this

Comment: If you've simply [Searched Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+highlight+the+menu+item+of+current+page+stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PRFFU73ZOozMrQef-YDoCw#q=how+to+highlight+the+menu+item+of+current+page+stackoverflow&rls=en&safe=active) you'll get a page full of stack overflow results alone..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight selected menu item when on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696836/highlight-selected-menu-item-when-on-page)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

---

```
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:500px;
}
li
{
 float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;  
    
    background-color:#003366;
    padding:10px;
       
}
a
{
   color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li.active {
    background-color:red;
    text-transform:uppercase;
   
}
li.active a{
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
   
}
```

**JQuery:**

---

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   $('li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

**Output:**

---

[image]

---

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zBws/13/)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PCh5f/)**

> Using jQuery you can highlight your current active menu

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
<a class="scroll" href="#intro">Home</a>

<a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>

<a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>

<a class="scroll" href="#team">Team</a>

<a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

<a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>

</div>
```

**css:**

```
.menu a:hover {
    background:#e9d319;
    color: #000;
}
.menu a.active {
    background:#e9d319;
    color: #000;
}
```

**js:**

```
$(".menu a").click(function() {
    $(".menu a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: When entering in website home page is become active . how to make?

Answer (score 1):

```
<i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
<a class="scroll" href="#intro">Home</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>

a.active
 {
 background:#e9d319;
 color: #000;
 }


 $(function(){

        $("a[href='#intro']").addClass("active");

    $("a.scroll ").click(function() {
        $("a.scroll").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmN89/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a[href='#intro']").addClass("active");

// This will highlight Home when your page will be loaded first

//This will highlight link when ever you click

    $(".menu a").click(function() {
        $(".menu a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: When loading a website home page is become active always. how to make?

Comment: I have Updated my answer...please check it

Comment: Check again please. @user35767

Comment: I have added another answer check It.. @user35767